# Generic Delegate Type Declaration Syntax

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

Non-generic delegate declaration is done as follows:

```
delegate void Print(int arg);
```

where `void` is a *return type* and `int` is the *argument type*.

A Generic delegate declaration is as below:

```
delegate void Print<T> (T arg);
```

where `void` is again the *return* type and `T` in parentheses is *generic argument type*.

Now we already know the return-type and arguments type then why do we require extra Type in angle bracktes **`Print<T>`** ? What does it signify ?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<T>` in `Print<T>` is needed to tell the compiler that you are intending to create a generic method.  Otherwise it could think `T` is some type, rather than a type parameter.  While intuitively you can infer what the author meant, the compiler is more literal about it.

Comment: +1, but there is potential second half if it is used inside generic class (added one more answer).

Answer (score 4):

It tells the compiler he is dealing with a generic method.

What you are suggesting is that the compiler will infer that this declaration is generic:

```
delegate void Print (T arg)
```

what happens in the presence of

```
class T { }
```

?

Answer (score 4):

Without that "extra type" in the bracket, there's no way the C# compiler can know if it should treat `T` in the parameter list as a generic type or it should expect a type whose name is really `T` as in `class T {}`.

Answer (score 2):

Sort of side note: `delegate void Print(T arg);` is perfectly valid syntax inside generic class and it means "this delegate takes the same type as `arg` as whole class" (assuming T is generic type for the class).

You can also declare `delegate void Print2<T>(T arg);` in the same class. The meaning (and comiler warns you) is different: the delegate uses any type as argument, and `T` is unrelated to the `T` used in the class (note that is bad and confusing idea to do so in your code).

```
class GenericClass<T>
{
   delegate void Print(T arg); // T is the same as T in the class

   delegate void Print2<T>(T arg); // T is unrelated to T in the class.
}
```

Similar code with functions:

```
using System;
class Program {
void Main()
{
  var x = new A<int>();
  // x.Print("abc");  - compile time error
  x.Print(1); // Print only accepts same Int32 type 

  x.Print2(1);     // Print2 can use as the same Int32 used for class
  x.Print2("abc"); // as well any other type like string.
}

public class A<T>
{
   public void Print(T arg)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Print:{0} = {1}", arg.GetType().FullName, arg);
   }
   public void Print2<T>(T arg)
   {
Console.WriteLine("PRINT2:{0} = {1}", arg.GetType().FullName, arg);
   }
}
}
```